# How do I usb tether my Cyanogen modded G1's internet connection to my Toshiba Tecra 8000 running Xubuntu?

Tags: usb, android, xubuntu, cellular-internet

I have usb-tethering enabled in my phone.  It works fine with Vista.  When I plug my phone into my Tecra 8000 laptop running Xubuntu, dmesg shows: "usb 1-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 8".  I see that the OS has detected it as a storage device, but I can't get it to function correctly as a network device.  `/dev/us*` shows no usb0, but it does show

```
/dev/usbdev1.1_ep00 /dev/usbdev1.1_ep81 /dev/usbdev1.8_ep00 ... usbdev1.8_ep83
```

I could just use the wireless tether app for android, but I can't get my Netgear wg511 v2 (made in China) wireless card to work in this laptop either.  But that's another post for later.

Comment: Please don't double post.

Comment: The other one has been deleted.

Comment: Did you enable USB tethering on the phone before connecting it ?